# How do I get the timing of an evaluation after it has already finished?

Tags: front-end, cells, timing, history

Sometimes I forget to add `Timing[]` to my evaluation and only notice it once it has already finished. Some of my calculations take hours or even days, so I don't want to restart the entire evaluation just to add `Timing[]` to it.

Is there a way to know the execution time of my evaluation *after* it has already finihsed, without relaunching the entire process?

Comment: this may be useful: [Extracting notebook history programmatically](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/154496/125)

Comment: If your code generates an Output `Cell` then you can find the evaluation time as the difference between `CellChangeTimes` of the Output and Input `Cell`s.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov That sounds interesting, can you perhaps give an example in the form of an answer?

Comment: @Flermat After thinking I must confess that I was mistaken: `CellChangeTimes` of the Input `Cell` contains last edititing time, not the time when the `Cell` was evaluated. So in this way we can get only an *upper bound* of the evaluation time.

Comment: Maybe [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/201819/show-timing-of-every-output/201830?r=SearchResults#201830) will help you.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### The case when the evaluation is finished

> Some of my calculations take hours or even days, so I don't want to restart the entire evaluation just to add `Timing[]` to it.

If your code generates an Output `Cell` then you can find at least an ***upper bound*** of the evaluation time as the difference between last [`CellChangeTimes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellChangeTimes.html) of the Output and Input `Cell`s. It can be very close to the actual evaluation time if you edited the Input `Cell` just before evaluating it. In this case you can simply paste and evaluate the following code **right after** the Output `Cell`:

```
DateDifference @@ 
 Last /@ Flatten /@ 
   CurrentValue[PreviousCell[CellStyle -> #] & /@ {"Input", "Output"}, CellChangeTimes]
```

---

### The case when the evaluation is still running

If the evaluation is still running you can try to set the `EvaluationCompletionAction -> "ShowTiming"` option ***before the evaluation has finished*** using [The Options Inspector](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OptionInspector.html) (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> on Windows):

[image: screenshot1]

On the above screenshot, this option is set on the `$FrontEnd` level ("Global Preferences"), but it is sufficient to set it only on the Notebook level for the Notebook where your evaluation is still running.

If you succeed in this, after finishing the evaluation you'll see the timing in the [`WindowStatusArea`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WindowStatusArea.html) of the notebook (located at the lower-left corner of the notebook as shown in the answer by [Jason B.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/184880/280)):

[image: screenshot2]

Note that the timing includes **the complete evaluation time**, not the time spent after you have set the option! This proves that FrontEnd measures evaluation time even when the option isn't set, and hence it should be theoretically possible to get this information even after finishing the evaluation (but I still don't know how [image: :idontnow:]).

P.S. Related Wolfram Community discussion: https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2327797

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you!

Answer (score 15):

Evaluate

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, EvaluationCompletionAction -> "ShowTiming"]
```

and then the evaluation time for the last evaluation will be shown in the lower left corner of the notebook:

[image]

Like many front end options, this setting is sticky. Set it once, and forget it; it also works across all versions of *Mathematica* installed.

Comment: Too bad there wasn't a way of finding the timing retrospectively. (In this approach, you must evaluate the SetOptions before running the time consuming command).

Comment: That doesn't really seem like a limitation to me. Finding the timing of the *currently evaluating* cell is an edge case. By using this setting, you get the timing for all future evaluations.

Comment: @bills I've added new section into my answer where I explain how this option can be set *during evaluation*.

Answer (score 8):

This is not immediately an answer to OP's question but it does provide an initialization code which one can use in all her/his files so that they do not have to worry about forgetting inserting `Timing` commands.

One can simply define a new variable, say **duration**, and record the evaluation of each calculation to this variable in the background.

Following code is sufficient for that:

```
ClearAll[duration,durationTemp];
$PreRead := ((durationTemp = AbsoluteTime[]); Function[#]);
$Post := ((duration[$Line] = AbsoluteTime[] - durationTemp);Function[#]);
```

What it does is to record the absolute time when the input is given and calculate the time passed when the evaluation finishes. This is done for each calculation, and recorded with input line so that `duration[n]` gives the time spent for the calculation of `Out[n]`.

As an example:

```
In[4]:= 1+1
Out[4]= 2
In[5]:= Pause[2]
In[6]:= Pause[5]
?duration

Global`duration
duration[3]=0.000351

duration[4]=0.000115

duration[5]=2.000717

duration[6]=5.000930
```

This is the most basic form; but one can modify `duration` function so that it counts in minutes instead of seconds, and it may garbage collect itself (say only keeps last 30 entries).

One can actually easily implement last idea using `Associations`. Specifically, below code does the same job using associations, and also only keeps last $n$ entries, where $n$ is set by `durationLength`:

```
ClearAll[duration, durationLength];
duration = <||>;
durationLength = 3;
$PreRead := (durationTemp = AbsoluteTime[]; Function[#]);
$Post := (If[KeyExistsQ[duration, $Line - durationLength], 
   KeyDropFrom[duration, $Line - durationLength]; 
   AssociateTo[duration, $Line -> AbsoluteTime[] - durationTemp], 
   AssociateTo[duration, $Line -> AbsoluteTime[] - durationTemp]]; 
   Function[#]);
```

As an example:

```
In[6]:= 1+1
Out[6]= 2
In[7]:=Pause[1]
In[8]:=Pause[2]
In[9]:=Pause[3]

?duration

Global`duration
duration=<|7->1.000416,8->2.001829,9->3.001157|>
```

Depending on the conditions, it may actually be a better idea to dedicate a stream to this and let it record the times to a file in the background. For example, one can use `OpenWrite[]` to create a temporary file per session, but I cannot imagine any scenario for which writing to a file is better than having this variable if the file is to be cleared after session ends (assuming session times are not extremely long). However, if one wants to keep a long record, then dedicating a file for this data and using `OpenAppend` to add these information to the same file may be useful. For example, if one has a 6 month long project and expects to have thousands of evaluation whose timing information happens to be useful data, then this may be relevant.