# Show timing of every output

Tags: date-and-time, customization, cells, output, timing

I know I can follow [Wolfram's guide](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/DisplayTheTimingOfAnEvaluationInANotebookWindow.html) and enable `"ShowTiming"` to show the timing of the previous command at the bottom of the window.

[image: Red is "ShowTiming" and green is "AddTimeStamp"]

Additionally, I can enable `"AddTimeStamp"` to show when each cell is evaluated next to the cell.  I was wondering if I could sorta combine `"ShowTiming"` and `"AddTimeStamp"` and show how long each output takes NEXT to the output cell (replacing the timestamp).  So instead of the output cells showing the timestamp, it would instead show the timing.

I know I could calculate this myself by subtracting the output date from the input date, but it would be more convenient to have this happen automatically.

Comment: What do you want to have happen when there is no output cell to attach the timing to?

Comment: Would you give me an example?  Like if I suppress the output with `;`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a Mathematica 12 stylesheet solution that adds the "ShowTiming" status area to each output cell label:

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], EvaluationCompletionAction] = {"ShowTiming"};

SetOptions[
    EvaluationNotebook[],
    StyleDefinitions->Notebook[
        {
        Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions->"Default.nb"]],
        Cell[StyleData["Input"],
            CellEpilog :> With[{time = AbsoluteCurrentValue["WindowStatusArea"]},
                If[CurrentValue[NextCell[], CellStyle] === {"Output"},
                    SetOptions[NextCell[], CellLabel -> time<>" Out["<>ToString[$Line-1]<>"]="]
                ]
            ]
        ]
        },
        StyleDefinitions->"PrivateStylesheetFormatting.nb"
    ]
]
```

Comment: I was confused why it didn't work and now I know, one needs to have `EvaluationCompletionAction` set to `"ShowTiming"`. p.s. even then it can't handle multi output cells from single input. (Don't want to be picky, just giving a feedback.)

Comment: @Kuba Thanks for mentioning the EvaluationCompletionAction issue! Yes, multiple outputs are an issue.

Comment: This isn't working for me.  Which I think has something to do with [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/201822/cannot-install-mathematica-12-on-macos-mojave-front-end-completely-unresponsive).  I get a `StringJoin::string` error saying `StringJoin: String expected at position 1 in Automatic <> Out[1]=.`

Comment: @MaxCoplan It seems that obtaining the value of the window status area is an M12 feature.

Comment: Well, it seems I'll have to wait until that's resolved to get the benefits of it.  I was able to confirm that your solution works though, using the window-resizing trick.  So I can go ahead and mark that as right