# Mathematica 12 not responding on Catalina

Tags: mac-os-x

This is on Catalina while running Mathematica 12 (64-bit version which is technically supported on Catalina). I can open notebooks but they seem unresponsive to typing or scrolling. However, if I drag or resize the window then I can see the changes I made. I am unsure if the issue is with Mathematica or with Catalina. I wanted to post here in case anyone has faced similar issues / knows a solution. I will be contacting Wolfram tomorrow.

Comment: Have you tried searching this site for "unresponsive" or something else that describes the situation?  It may be a problem that has occurred on previous releases and/or system.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did find a solution that worked. Posting it below.

Answer (score 5):

Executing the following in the Terminal solves the issue:

```
defaults write com.wolfram.Mathematica NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance -bool YES
```

More details here:
[Cannot install Mathematica 12 on macOS Mojave. Front-End completely unresponsive](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/201822/cannot-install-mathematica-12-on-macos-mojave-front-end-completely-unresponsive)